# Spectrogram for image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am currently trying to replecate the paper: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fneur.2019.00806/full

They achieve above 90% acc

Database: https://physionet.org/content/chbmit/1.0.0/

However this seems more challenging than i thought. The data i'm using consists of EEG with a sampling rate of 256 hz.

I've read that with epilepsy and EEG the most appearent difference between seizure and no-seizure is to be found at the lower frequencies therefore i have implemented a low pass filter using scipy:

[image]

My windows consists of 4 seconds of data = 4*256 = samples. Below i have the raw data and when filter is applied:

[image]

I have tried many different configurations to create my spectrograms for the cnn (this is the latest):

```
Fs = 256
interval = 128   # ... the interval size,
overlap = interval * 0.95  # ... and the overlap intervals

import matplotlib.colors as colors
from scipy.stats import lognorm
#plt.ylim(0, 10)
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(
    np.array(filtered),                # Provide the signal,
    fs=Fs,                # ... the sampling frequency,
    nperseg=interval,
    noverlap=overlap, mode='psd')

#Sxx = 10 * np.log10(Sxx)
normalize_color= colors.LogNorm(vmin=np.amin(Sxx), vmax=np.amax(Sxx))
                          # ... the number of samples to overlap,
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx, norm=normalize_color,
            cmap='jet')# Plot the result
```

which outputs the following (something weird going on at the highest freqs):

[image]

My problem is that when i use these different spectrograms as input i cannot achieve a validation acc above 50-60%. I've tried increasingly using dropout, data augmentation, reducing learning rate and different networks (resnet, inception, vgg16, effiecency net + my own shallow model)

During training i undersample my data so i have an equal amount of seizure non seizure data. I have been implementing an overlaping window function to generate more seizure data. I have around 2000 images of each class.

Here's my custom cnn:

```
model = Sequential()

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',
                        input_shape=(299,299,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

It seems like something is wrong with my input. Is 1028 samples in a window not enough for FFT Spectrograms?

Comment: Why do you think that something is wrong you your code?

Comment: Also why do you use Conv2D when your signal is 1D?

Comment: I am trying to replicate that paper i mentioned in the start. I am converting the signal data to images using FFT. However i am no where near the acc the authors of that paper is mentioning...

Comment: The Fs, interval and overlap_interval are very important, they affect you signal a lot . The same with your low pass filter. I dont think there is anything wrong with the code here. You just need to play around with the parameters. I dont even think that the problem is with the CNN. You need to prepare the data carefully. What is the correct data prepossessing, I cant tell you you have to play with the data and find it.  It seems that you are heavily manipulating your data, so be careful that you are not chopping or distorting information from the original signal. The code is fine.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the paper could be shady and make false claims.I have seen papers that are reporting extremely high accuracies for selected data but they dont mention that. They just try to seem awesome. Some people only keep the data that make their method work well. Don't trust it blindly.

Comment: hmm... ye properbly it's just sad :P... it's for my master thesis so i really wanted to achieve something useful. I will try to increase window size. I have only read up on FFT can the solution be to go into STFT or will it not make much of a difference ? There's also this paper https://smorettini.github.io/general/2020/07/21/CNNs-on-CHB-MIT/ which uses much larger windows 30second win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments contains the answer. he Fs, interval and overlap_interval are very important, they affect you signal a lot . The same with your low pass filter. I dont think there is anything wrong with the code here. You just need to play around with the parameters. I dont even think that the problem is with the CNN. You need to prepare the data carefully. What is the correct data prepossessing, I cant tell you you have to play with the data and find it. It seems that you are heavily manipulating your data, so be careful that you are not chopping or distorting information from the original signal. The code is fine.